# Call a stored procedure with the same name using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, procedure

I have two stored procedures in my database Postgres, both have the same name but the difference are the parameters.

**procedure1(::string, ::integer, ::string, ::integer)**

**procedure1(::string, ::integer, ::integer)**

In PDO doing bindParam correct, is coming STR, INT, INT but the prepere always performs procedure1.

How do I get him to understand what I call the procedure2?

Some information for more help? I clear? thanks

EDIT ===

...

```
$bounds = null; // forced for debug

if(!is_null($bounds)){
  $query = "SELECT procedure1(:name, :domain, :geo, :userid)";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam('name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam('domain', $idDomain, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam('geo', $geoString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam('userid', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);   
}else{
  $query = "SELECT procedure1(:name, :domain, :userid)";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam('name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam('domain', $idDomain, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam('userid', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
}
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

...

The error it gives is that he is running a procedure that requires four parameters

Comment: Please show the concrete code you have.

Comment: Does PDO even support postgres's sproc overloading?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `$query` statements to explicitly tell PDO the types, and to avoid extra code switch to `bindValue` (PDO uses the PARAM flags to format SQL, not to cast data types):

```
$bounds = null; // forced for debug

if(!is_null($bounds)){
  $query = "SELECT procedure1(:name::VARCHAR, :domain::INTEGER, :geo::VARCHAR, :userid::INTEGER)";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindValue('name', $name);
  $stmt->bindValue('domain', $idDomain);
  $stmt->bindValue('geo', $geoString);
  $stmt->bindValue('userid', $userId);
}else{
  $query = "SELECT procedure1(:name::VARCHAR, :domain::INTEGER, :userid::INTEGER)";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindValue('name', $name);
  $stmt->bindValue('domain', $idDomain);
  $stmt->bindValue('userid', $userId); 
}
$result = $stmt->execute();
```